# "Invalid tracking Id. Aborting hit." for Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have 2 ecommerce sites hosted on Shopify and Google Analytics properly implemented on both sites. I check my analytics daily, all that's good. Recently, I've been trying to do [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) every time someone adds a product to their shopping cart.

Pretty much following [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/09/20/leveraging-google-analytics-event-tracking-on-your-shopify-store.aspx).

So I added the following to my add to cart buttons: onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Products', 'Add To Cart', 'some-product-title']);" . This is working perfectly on my first ecommerce site, I see the event being tracked in Google Analytics.

On my second site however, it's not going through and I'm getting an error... using [the GA Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna), I tried doing that event tracking command in the console: _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Products', 'Add To Cart', 'some-product-title'])

I get the following error: Invalid tracking Id. Aborting hit.

What does this mean? Trying to figure out how GA is being implemented differently on both sites, but can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your new site is using [Universal Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) (analytics.js)? If that is the case, you'll have to update your [event syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) to:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Products', 'Add To Cart', 'some-product-title');
```