# Google analytics: error Invalid tracking Id. Aborting hit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm receiving on this site [DSA.dk](http://www.dsa.dk/search.aspx#?cludoquery=job&cludopage=1&cludorefpt=Din%20Sundhedsfaglige%20A-kasse%20-%20kun%20for%20sundhedsuddannede&cludorefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dsa.dk%2F) from Google Analytics error Invalid tracking Id. Aborting hit. I checked this with the Google analytics debug tool and I cannot find a solution to this problem.

The debugger shows me the error happening here:

```
})) : "undefined" != typeof _gaq ? 0 == e ? _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "Search - ZeroResults", this.searchUrl + t]) : _gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "Search", this.searchUrl + t]) : (0 == e && ga("send", "event", "Search", "ZeroResults", this.params.query ? this.params.query : "Blank"),
```

However I need a suggestion what to check and to resolve this issue.

Comment: for starters i would upgrade your tracking code your still using classic analytics   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: Hi @DalmTo could you please provide me an example? I'm stuck on it from half day now.

Comment: Read though the link you shouldn't be using _gaq.push this is old code you should update your site to the new system.

Comment: @DalmTo I know that and this is why the code was modified to this https://pastebin.com/qLrQc3Zg but seems something is wrong. I have and if which checks which type is and do the right one operation but something not working here. Could you please take a look and maybe give me a suggestion what to change? Thank you

Comment: @Jakub  hey you're using a deprecated method on the initiation of the code. The error shows hows to fix:" Method _getTracker is deprecated. Use _createTracker instead. "  if you want more help show the main snippet (the one where you execute the UA instance). Also, remember that some features of classic (AKA legacy GA) are currently stopping working

Comment: @Jakub The issue comes from the thr following sentence, here is where you have to change the _gettracker, but I see another code launching pageviews correctly BTW. 
        try {
            var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-10658190-1");
            pageTracker._trackPageview();
        } catch (err) { }

Comment: @KeemPaulosPlaza Thank you for the suggestions. I get that information to the customer and they will provide the updates need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid tracking Id. Aborting hit." for Event Tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772574/invalid-tracking-id-aborting-hit-for-event-tracking)